# How to unchecked checkbox automatically after multiple textbox is filled?

Tags: javascript, textbox, jsfiddle

I tried using this

```
<input type="text" name="commentID" id="commentID" onkeyup="userTyped('skipID', this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="skipID" value="N" id="skipID" checked="checked"  />
```

and the javascript

```
function userTyped(commen, e){
if(e.value.length > 0){
document.getElementById(commen).checked=false;
}else{
document.getElementById(commen).checked=true;
}}​
```

It works on JSfiddle, ["EXAMPLE"](http://jsfiddle.net/MAVLy/3) but i can't seem to make it work on dreamweaver, and only if I use one textbox, I want the checkbox to be unchecked automatically  only after three textbox is filled.

Comment: Do you use a JavaScript library?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I don't know which library should I use.

Comment: Doesn't work in jsFiddle for me. Also what do you mean it doesn't work in DW ??? Do you mean the live view in DW?

Comment: @jtheman I've updated the hyperlink to jsFiddle. Usinng jsFiddle, the checkbox will be unchecked after I type something inside the textbox, but it wont work in dreamweaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here http://jsfiddle.net/MAVLy/7/ is a rewritten function using jQuery with three textboxes. For readability I put textbox length in variables but you could omit that.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" class="enable" />
<input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" class="enable" />
<input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3" class="enable" />
<input type="checkbox" name="skipID" value="N" id="skipID" checked="checked"  />
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
  $('input.enable').keyup(function(){
    var t1 = $('#textbox1').val().length;
    var t2 = $('#textbox2').val().length;
    var t3 = $('#textbox3').val().length;
   if (t1==0 || t2==0 || t3==0) $('#skipID').attr('checked', true);
   else $('#skipID').attr('checked', false);
  });        
});
```

Alternative solution. This one applies to unlimited numbers of textboxes of the class `enable`

```
$(function(){
  $('input.enable').keyup(function(){
    var checked = false;
    $('input.enable').each(function(){
       if ($(this).val().length == 0) checked = true;
    });
    $('#skipID').attr('checked', checked);
  });        
});
```

Another jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MAVLy/8/

Comment: thanks, but how if i want the checkbox to be unchecked only after 3 textbox is filled ?

Comment: These solutions actually works. You could consider marking it as suggested answer or at least as helpful!!!